# Is it possible to customize TFS to provide user friendly forms for registering bugs?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, alm

I need to let users register bugs similar to how it is done in Bug tracking systems.

I'd like to create user friendly form with a layout which will guide user. Standard `Create New Workitem` interface is too overloaded for users.

Today we manually look through inbox and register bugs in TFS ourselves. This is really a pain. Users often do not mark the message in subject as a bug. You need to read it to understand user has a problem. Sometimes you need to ask them about the criticality level and what the deadlines for fixing it are.

It is easy to miss important message and this process distracts from main activity.

Answer (score 2):

(Based on you having Visual Studio and having already connected to TFS in there)

In Visual Studio, via the menu, choose Tools > Process Editor > Work Item Types > Open WIT from server

**EDIT: You will need to install the Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools Extension in Visual Studio to gain access to that menu option above**

You will then be presented with a popup box. At this point you will need to navigate to the Project Collection you wish to make changes in. Once selected you will then be presented with a list of forms you can edit. e.g. Task, Bug, Code Review etc.

If you select Task you will then be taken to a form where you will have 3 tabs. Fields, Layout and workflow. From here you have a certain level of customisation available.

I found a couple of articles (below) around customising templates. One is for TFS 2015, the other is for TFS 2013.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/12/10/adding-a-custom-field-to-a-work-item.aspx (TFS 2015)

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/customizing-team-foundation-server-2013/ (TFS 2013)

NOTE: Menu option **Open WIT from server** will make changes directly on the server. There are other option where you can make changes locally, then import those changes in. The above is just a way to get you to the screen to customise the forms so that you can take a look around.